# php xpath get specifc element by attribute

Tags: php, xpath, attributes, domdocument

I'm trying to get an element by an specific attribute (`"data-image-id"`).

I got this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$links = $xpath->query('//div[@data-image-id]/@data-image-id');
die(var_dump($links));
```

but I got the following:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#3 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }
```

I just want to get all elements with the attribute `"image-data-id"`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `data-image-id != image-data-id`. Show relevant part of your HTML